# Is IEEE 754 format when using soft, softfp, hard floating point the same?

Tags: floating-point, raspberry-pi, arm

TL;DR: How is 0x400921f4 the IEEE 754 representation of 3.1415801? Is this a soft-float somehow? What am I missing?

I am currently in the process of getting to know [crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.github.io/%20%22crosstool-NG) while building my own cross-compiler for the Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspberry Pi Zero W. (*1)

After reading documentation spread over their forums and wikis, I understood that the RPi3 and RPi0 compilers need to target different ARM architectures, ARMv7 and ARMv6 respectively. However, both SoCs have a floating-point unit, so I want to use hard floating point to match the rest of the Raspberry Pi libraries.

I tested my newly-built armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi-gcc 6.4.0 against the arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 4.9.3 available at the [RaspberryPi Tool repository](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools). I read up how to determine if an executable uses hard fp [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-using-the-hard-float-or-the-soft-float-version-of-debian). Sure enough, when I compile the following minimal test case.

I compile using `gcc -O0 -o main main.c` with both compilers. In the following:  main.rpi for my toolchain, main.hf for pre-built toolchain.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        printf("Hello, world %0.7f", 3.14158f);
        return 0;
}
```

`readelf -A main.rpi` does not return `Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers` when using my newly-built armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi-gcc, but it does when using the pre-built arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc using `readelf -A main.hf`. However, both executables run just fine on a default raspbian stretch image that supposedly only supports hard fp with the following output:

```
Hello, world 3.1415801
```

A weird oddity is that `ldd main.rpi` on the RPi itself just returns `not a dynamic executable` while it lists the dependencies just fine for `ldd main.hf`. Again, both run and give the expected output. `objdump -R` (run on the RPi) returns the same for both executables:

```
DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE
0002101c R_ARM_GLOB_DAT    __gmon_start__
0002100c R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   printf@GLIBC_2.4
00021010 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.4
00021014 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   __gmon_start__
00021018 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   abort@GLIBC_2.4
```

This got me concerned that I used `soft` or `softfp` instead of `hard` floating point. So I looked at a disassembly listing from both executables using `objdump -d` (run on the RPi):

```
main.rpi:
---------
0001045c <main>:
   1045c:       e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
   10460:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
   10464:       e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8
   10468:       e50b0008        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
   1046c:       e50b100c        str     r1, [fp, #-12]
   10470:       e3a02103        mov     r2, #-1073741824        ; 0xc0000000
   10474:       e59f3014        ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; 10490 <main+0x34>
   10478:       e59f0014        ldr     r0, [pc, #20]   ; 10494 <main+0x38>
   1047c:       ebffffa1        bl      10308 <printf@plt>
   10480:       e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
   10484:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
   10488:       e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
   1048c:       e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
   10490:       400921f4        .word   0x400921f4 <--- float 3.1415801 here
   10494:       00010508        .word   0x00010508 <--- pointer to format string
```

.

```
main.hf:
--------
000103f8 <main>:
   103f8:       e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
   103fc:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
   10400:       e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8
   10404:       e50b0008        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
   10408:       e50b100c        str     r1, [fp, #-12]
   1040c:       e59f0018        ldr     r0, [pc, #24]   ; 1042c <main+0x34>
   10410:       e3a02103        mov     r2, #-1073741824        ; 0xc0000000
   10414:       e59f3014        ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; 10430 <main+0x38>
   10418:       ebffffa1        bl      102a4 <printf@plt>
   1041c:       e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
   10420:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
   10424:       e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
   10428:       e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
   1042c:       000104a4        .word   0x000104a4 <--- pointer to format string
   10430:       400921f4        .word   0x400921f4 <--- float 3.1415801 here
```

To my big surprise both compilers produced the same result for main with minimal differences. (*2) Both look like hardfp to me.

I checked if maybe there was some trickery and the compiler placed the float in the actual string, but found none. Then I went and casually made sure that 0x400921f4 is indeed my floating point value 3.1415801 that gets printed. I checked using two online tools, [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and [here](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html). And that's when my understanding of floating point data apparently fell apart.

All converters tell me 3.1415801 should be 0x40490fa6 and the literal in both executables 0x400921f4 yields ~2.1426973. Are both compilers using a special (software?) floating-point format even though they indicate they use `Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754`? I always assumed software floating point is just regular IEEE 754, but computed in software and not a different format, though.

**I'm really confused at this point if I succeeded using hardfp and my reasoning is off or how to explain the obviously correct behavior when I don't even see the right floating-point constant in the disassembly.**

---

(*1) Since this is the first time I use crosstool-NG, I used their sample configuration `armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi`, but downgraded gcc to 6.4.0 and gdb to 7.12.1 to about match the cross-compiler toolchains available for Windows. I also targeted kernel 4.4.83 and up instead of 3.12.74.

(*2) I checked if maybe soft-float operations were hidden in printf@plt, but that was not the case. The assembly for both is (with different addresses):

```
00010308 <printf@plt>:
   10308:       e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
   1030c:       e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
   10310:       e5bcfcfc        ldr     pc, [ip, #3324]!        ; 0xcfc
```

Comment: although there is no reason to necessarily, I have not yet see a compiler use a different format when switching back and forth between hard and soft floating point.  but maybe those compilers are out there.

Comment: Hmmm... despite the answers, ISTM that `0x400921F4` is **part** of the hex representation of the bytes that form the 8-byte double `3.1415801` (full hex value: `0x400921F4BF5A1D83`). The 4-byte float value of `3.1415801f` is `0x40490FA6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the float is passed to printf() it gets promoted to double, and the compiler has optimized out the conversion. The representation of `(double)(3.14158f)` is `0x400921f4c0000000`. The MS part has gone into r3 and the LS part in r2.

Also, because printf() is variadic, the FP value is passed using integer registers in both cases (soft-float style).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick response. I guess I was just dense yesterday evening. Makes perfect sense. I'll wait a day or so and then accept!

Answer (score 0):

```
float  fun ( float a )
{
    return(a+1.234F);
}
```

with hard float

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   eddf 7a02   vldr    s15, [pc, #8]   ; c <fun+0xc>
   4:   ee30 0a27   vadd.f32    s0, s0, s15
   8:   4770        bx  lr
   a:   bf00        nop
   c:   3f9df3b6    svccc   0x009df3b6
```

with soft float

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
   2:   f24f 31b6   movw    r1, #62390  ; 0xf3b6
   6:   f6c3 719d   movt    r1, #16285  ; 0x3f9d
   a:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <__aeabi_fadd>
   e:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
```

same constant which is the correct constant.

But as pointed out in an answer that came in before I could get mine.  floating point in C is double unless otherwise specified, note the F at the end of my constant, without that the compiler has to promote to double to perform the operation (because that is what I told it to do by not putting an F, constants are considered double otherwise) then convert back to single to return.

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
   2:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <__aeabi_f2d>
   6:   a304        add r3, pc, #16 ; (adr r3, 18 <fun+0x18>)
   8:   e9d3 2300   ldrd    r2, r3, [r3]
   c:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <__aeabi_dadd>
  10:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <__aeabi_d2f>
  14:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
  16:   bf00        nop
  18:   c8b43958    ldmgt   r4!, {r3, r4, r6, r8, r11, r12, sp}
  1c:   3ff3be76    svccc   0x00f3be76
```